# How to convert Ignite queue to Spark Dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, ignite

We need to get the contents of Ignite Queue that holds large dataset in a cluster as Spark dataframe.

Currently we do it like below.

```
var array: Array[Row] = Array()
array = igniteQueue.toArray(array)
```

But this brings all the distributed contents of the igniteQueue to a single edge node as an array which causes overflow exception.

Is there a way to get igniteQueue data as Spark Dataframe? so that the data will be distributed

Thanks in Advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

Check [IgniteContext & IgniteRDD documentation](https://apacheignite-fs.readme.io/docs/ignitecontext-igniterdd) - it's the main entry point to Spark-Ignite integration.

Since IgniteRDD is a live view of Ignite cache, there is no need to explicitly load data to Spark application from Ignite. All RDD methods are available to use right away after an instance of IgniteRDD is created.

For example the following Scala code will find all values that contain the word "Ignite":

```
val cache = igniteContext.fromCache("partitioned")
val result = cache.filter(_._2.contains("Ignite")).collect()
```

Also, check this [Java example](https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/master/examples/src/main/spark/org/apache/ignite/examples/spark/SharedRDDExample.java)